# Could a thread change its belonging process?

Tags: multithreading, process, semantics

In fact it is a Microsoft interview question,

```
About the Thread and Process in Windows, which description(s) is(are) correct:(3 Points)
   A. One application in OS must have one Process, but not a necessary to have one Thread
   B. The Process could have its own Stack but the thread only could share the Stack of its parent Process
   C. Thread must belongs to a Process
   D. Thread could change its belonging Process
```

I have searched but still cannot get the answer.

Comment: Three of the answers are utterly ridiculous.  I suggest you search more thoroughly. Doesn't sound much like a Microsoft interview question to me.

Comment: @MartinJames It's a question in Microsoft written test last week.

Answer (score 0):

Could a thread could change its belonging Process - no.